# First and last entry for specific user and specific date and difference of hour in between that entry

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Please refer below table for more details.

```
1   vishal  10  7/4/2017 1:00:00 PM
2   rahul   12  7/4/2017 2:00:00 PM
3   sudha   15  7/4/2017 3:00:00 PM
4   vishal  10  7/4/2017 4:00:00 PM
5   vishal  10  7/4/2017 2:30:00 PM
6   vishal  10  7/4/2017 12:30:00 PM
7   vishal  10  6/4/2017 10:30:00 PM
8   vishal  10  10/4/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

I want below output

```
vishal  10  7/4/2017   12:30:00 PM 4:00:00 PM 3.5hrs
```

Note: Query has to be run on SQL server 2003.

Comment: can you explain how you get to your desired output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can do it, if i understood your question right

```
create table #table1 (field1 int, field2 varchar(10), field3 int, field4 datetime)
insert into #table1 values
   (1, 'vishal', 10, '20170704 1:00:00'),
   (2, 'rahul',  12, '20170704 2:00:00'),
   (3, 'sudha',  15, '20170704 3:00:00'),
   (4, 'vishal', 10, '20170704 4:00:00'),
   (5, 'vishal', 10, '20170704 2:30:00'),
   (6, 'vishal', 10, '20170704 00:30:00'),
   (7, 'vishal', 10, '20170604 10:30:00'),
   (8, 'vishal', 10, '20171004 00:00:00')

select field2, 
       field3, 
       convert(date, field4), 
       min(field4), 
       max(field4), 
       Datediff(second,Min(field4),Max(field4))/3600.00 
from   #table1
group by field2, field3, convert(date, field4)

drop table #table1
```

the outcome is this :

```
rahul   12  2017-07-04  4/07/2017 2:00:00   4/07/2017 2:00:00   0   
sudha   15  2017-07-04  4/07/2017 3:00:00   4/07/2017 3:00:00   0   
vishal  10  2017-06-04  4/06/2017 10:30:00  4/06/2017 10:30:00  0   
vishal  10  2017-07-04  4/07/2017 0:30:00   4/07/2017 4:00:00   3.5 
vishal  10  2017-10-04  4/10/2017           4/10/2017           0
```

Comment: well, it's working but additionally, I wanted only following data.vishal  10  2017-07-04  4/07/2017 0:30:00   4/07/2017 4:00:00   3.5 
vishal  10  2017-10-04  4/10/2017           4/10/2017           0

Comment: If you only want data for Vishal than you can add a where clause like where field2 = 'Vishal'

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work,

```
SELECT Name,
       Max(Value) AS Value,
       Cast(Date_Time as Date) AS Date,
       Max(Date_Time) AS Max_Date_Time,
       Min(Date_Time) AS Min_Date_Time,
       Datediff(second,Min(Date_Time),Max(Date_Time))/3600.00 AS Time_Diff
 FROM  #Your_Table 
 Group by Name, Cast(Date_Time as Date)
```

Note: Working in SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Using DATEDIFF, LTRIM,RIGHT and Group By

```
select name as Name,Number as Value,
convert(date,startdate) as [Date],
LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),MIN(convert(datetime,convert(varchar,startdate,109))),22),11)) AS MIN_Date,
LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),MAX(convert(datetime,convert(varchar,startdate,109))),22),11)) AS MAX_Date,
convert(varchar(50),convert(numeric(8,1),(DATEDIFF(second,MIN(convert(datetime,convert(varchar,startdate,109))),max(startdate))/3600.00)))+' hrs' as TimeDifference
from my_table_new group by name,convert(date,startdate),Number
```

OUTPUT :

```
Name    Value   Date    MIN_Date    MAX_Date    TimeDifference
rahul   12  2017-07-04  2:00:00 PM  2:00:00 PM  0.0 hrs
sudha   15  2017-07-04  3:00:00 PM  3:00:00 PM  0.0 hrs
vishal  10  2017-06-04  10:30:00 PM 10:30:00 PM 0.0 hrs
vishal  10  2017-07-04  12:30:00 PM 4:00:00 PM  3.5 hrs
vishal  10  2017-10-04  12:00:00 AM 12:00:00 AM 0.0 hrs
```